# What is the best way for creating default emails?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, templates

I'm planing on using `PHPMailer` which comes along with Wordpress.
I will be submitting HTML e-mail including alternative txt mail using SMTP.

I will have different e-mails depending on user action (registration, request etc).

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but I'm thinking of creating a folder containing HTML files, e.g. `/emails/confirm_registration.html`.

Then I will fetch the content and put it in the body of the mail `$mail->Body=$message;`

I also want to include variables such as the users name in the body text.

**So this is my question:**

Should I put the body text inside a function, call it with parameters and then return content?

Or should I add placeholders like `{first-name}` in the HTML and use `str_replace('{first-name}','Some name')` once I've returned the html content?

If you have better suggestions, I would greatly appreciate that.

Comment: I think your second option allows you more flexibility. That way the variety of emails you create all load / send from the same function all you have to do is pass a "template" file to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest you use SwiftMailer as your email library
http://swiftmailer.org/
This library is really stable, elegant and complete. Your method of replacing placeholders with text is standard and works, if I recall many common templating libraries like smarty for example use a very similar methodology.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've looked at `Swiftmailer`, but then I found out that WP already has `PHPMailer`, so I thought giving that a go first.

Answer (score 0):

I always use this method in my custom programming, it seems perfect to me.

Comment: which you mention in your question :)

Comment: I had to options. I went for the second option.